# Red Hat PXE server setup behind a dhcp firewall

Tags: networking, rhel, system-installation, dhcp, pxe

---

**Physical Network Setup:**

---

A third party hardware firewall includes a `DHCP` service which maps `MAC` addresses of connected machines to local IP addresses.

A physical box with a CentOS 7 host OS also has a guest CentOS 7 OS running inside it.  Both this physical host and its guest have IP addresses that are assigned by the hardware firewall connected to the physical box.

Multiple other physical boxes DO NOT HAVE OPERATING SYSTEMS INSTALLED ON THEM YET, AND REQUIRE NETWORK INSTALLATION OF A HOST OPERATING SYSTEM.  Each of these other physical boxes is also connected via Ethernet to the same hardware firewall/`dhcp`-server.

---

**The Question:**

---

> **How would a PXE server need to be installed on the CentOS 7 Guest mentioned above in order to be able to provide network installation of Host CentOS 7 operating systems on the other physical boxes that have Ethernet connections to the hardware firewall?**

---

**Reasoning:**

---

I frame the question this way because [this tutorial](https://www.unixmen.com/install-pxe-server-and-configure-pxe-client-on-centos-7/) and this [Red Hat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-installation-server-setup.html) both indicate that the `PXE` server must also act as a `DHCP` server.  Given that `DHCP` is also provided by the hardware firewall in the setup described above, it would seem that a conflict would be created if the CentOS 7 Guest described above were configured to act as a `DHCP` server.

For example, the tutorial in [the link above](https://www.unixmen.com/install-pxe-server-and-configure-pxe-client-on-centos-7/) includes the following `yum install` command:

```
yum install httpd xinetd syslinux tftp-server -y
```

I imagine that perhaps `xinetd` and `syslinux` might not be required on a CentOS 7 -hosted `PXE` server running behind a hardware firewall that provides its own `DHCP`.

Please advise how to frame the creation of a functioning `PXE` server in this environment.

Comment: How much can you modify the 3rd party firewall to e.g. specify the `next-server` and `filename` options? Otherwise, another kluge is to put the servers-to-be-installed on a local switch with the centos server and run a rogue DHCP server on the cento server...

Comment: @thrig The hardware firewall is a Zywall 110.  The admin server that has the existing CentOS 7 installations is just a converted desktop, so it does not have multiple Ethernet jacks.  The recipient servers are bonafide servers that might be able to connect to multiple external hardware, but I would have to physically examine them when I am at their physical location next.  Does this information help?

Comment: You don't really need a second NIC, you just need your DHCP server to be the first to respond (yes, it's a kluge...)

Comment: @thrig From [this link](https://www.unixmen.com/install-pxe-server-and-configure-pxe-client-on-centos-7) from the OP, the contents of `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` to change are: `allow booting;  allow bootp;  option option-128 code 128 = string;  option option-129 code 129 = text;  next-server 192.168.1.5;  filename "pxelinux.0";`  Where `pxelinux.0` is `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.0` on the CentOS 7 guest mentioned above which is at `192.168.1.5` assigned by the hardware firewall.  How would I configure this using the environment described in the OP?